# What to call the initial members of an ordered set?

Tags: terminology

If I have an ordered set `X = {a, b, c}` and another ordered set `Y = {a, b}`, I know that that `Y` is a subset of `X` but I also want to convey that `Y` is the prefix of `X` if that makes sense.  Is there a name for that?

Comment: Y would usually be called an initial segment of X.

Comment: @Miha: "Initial segment" is very common for well-ordered sets, less so for partially ordered sets (or for totally ordered sets that don't have a least element).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept you may be looking for is either an 
**initial segment** or **downward closed set.**

If $(X,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set, then a subset $Y\subseteq X$ is a *downward closed subset of $X$* if and only if for all $y\in Y$, if $x\in X$ and $x\leq y$, then $x\in Y$. When $X$ is well-ordered (so that every nonempty subset has a first element), then such a set is usually called an *initial segment* rather than merely a downward closed set. This is sometimes also used for totally ordered sets <strike>with a least element, but not so much for sets that don't have a minimum, since 'initial segment' carries the connotation of a "beginning"</strike>. Thanks to JDH for pointing out my error of statement here; initial segment is common for any linear order, not only well orders or linear orders with least element.

Of course, any finite totally ordered set is well-ordered, so that may be the only case you are interested in, in which case "initial segment" is the common term.

Comment: Arturo, the initial segment terminology is very commonly used for any linear order, whether well-ordered or not. Also, in a partial order, being downward-closed is the same as being an *open* set in the usual topology having a basis consisting of the lower cones.

Comment: @JDH: Thanks for the correction; I've never encountered it except for total orders with least element, and thought it was uncommon; I bow to your superior knowledge here.